# Can't evaluate expression inside AngularJs Controller

Tags: angularjs

Code for controller:

```
angular
.module('ToDo')
.controller('todoController',['$scope','dbTask', function ($scope,dbTask){
        var t = new dbTask();

        $scope.tasks = [];
        $scope.testObject = 'tesobject';}
```

Code for page:

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<!--Remote Object-->
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="farriskhalid__Task__c" jsShorthand="dbTask" fields="CreatedDate">
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="farriskhalid__newtask_del__c" jsShorthand="dbTaskField" />
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>


<!--begin ng-app ToDoList-->
<body ng-App="ToDo">
    <h1 class="text-center">To Do List</h1><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- dynamic view -->
        <div ng-view="ng-view"></div>

    </div>

<!--Linking all js files + bootstrap-->
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

 <!--including module + all controllers-->
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.angularToDo,'App.js')}"/>
<!-- <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularTask,'todo-database.js')}"/> -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularTask,'todo-Controller.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularTask,'todo-New-Controller.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularTask,'todo-Edit-Controller.js')}"/>
</body><br/></apex:page>
```

Code for App.js :

```
angular

.module('ToDo',['ngRoute'])

.constant('resourceUrl','/resource/'+Date.now()+'/AngularTask')

.config(['$routeProvider','resourceUrl', function($routeProvider, resourceUrl) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: resourceUrl+'/tasklist/todo-list.html',
            controller: 'todoController'
        })
        .when('/new', {
            templateUrl: resourceUrl+'/tasklist/todo-new.html',
            controller: 'todoNewController'
        })
        .when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: resourceUrl+'/tasklist/todo-edit.html',
            controller: 'todoEditController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        });
}])

.controller()

//makes proxy object available to rest of ToDo
.service('dbTask', function() {
    return SObjectModel.dbTask;
});
```

WHAT the Page looks like :
[image]

Help; I'm pulling out my hair trying to find whats wrong.......

Comment: Best asked on an Angular forum. Presumably you have no JavaScript errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Fixed. Now I just can't retrieve custom object records from salesforce.......do you know how to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Keith. I forgot to use google chrome to inspect.  :P

Comment: I assume (but have not done it) that you can make requests in your controller and add the results to `$scope` in the callback; see [Retrieving Records with Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve.htm) as the JavaScript API is generated into your page.

Comment: lol. I figured it out. then came back in here to type this message. but yeah I basically looked at that page from google. thanks keith